# Getting below errors while running npm start command

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack

Getting below errors in console while running npm start command

[image]

I've tried multiple options
 - Remove all npm packages and re-installed it
 - Clear npm caches
 - Re-clone repo

Comment: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/959  might be this bug.. one of plugins of webpack is not working.. whats the version of webpack you using ?

Comment: @MurtazaHussain I'm using below webpack's plugins

"webpack": "~4.8.3",
 "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.1.0",
 "webpack-cli": "^2.1.3",
 "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.14"
 "webworkify-webpack": "^2.1.3"
"clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.19",
"copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.6.0",
 "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
 "progress-bar-webpack-plugin": "^1.11.0",
 "terser-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.3",